# Verify the entry in the text file using HashMap/HashTablw/2D array

Tags: java

I have a text file which will doing fruit discovery and store Fruit name as `fruit1` and time as `time1`. Please refer to the following for the data structure

```
Banana 12:10:11
Apple 12:10:11
Watermelon 12:16:10
Pineapple 12:16:10
Grape 12:30:16
```

I want to make sure that the timestamps wrote to the text file is the most updated timestamps with correct fruit and single entry only. For example, if `Banana` found on `12:31:18`, it's will replace the older banana's record which is `12:10:11`, so the updated file will look like

```
Apple 12:10:11
Watermelon 12:16:10
Pineapple 12:16:10
Grape 12:30:16
Banana 12:30:16
```

This is my own pseudo code to achieve my purpose.

```
Read data(fruit1,time1) from text file
Store into HashMap/2D Array/HashTable/
    If HashMap is empty
       write fruit2/time2 
    Else if fruit2 = fruit1
       Check the time? 
          If time2 = time1
             Ignore 
          Else update the time
    Else if fruit2 not equal fruit1
       Check next element ?
         If exsit ?
            If fruit2 = fruit1
                Check the time ?
                   If time2 = time1 
                      Ignore 
                   else update the time 
         Else if fruit1 not equal fruit1
             Back to check next element
```

Anyone here can suggest a better way to do this ? Do my own design pseudo code having some insufficient or out of logic ? Please advise any suitable method

Comment: A database would be well suited to this problem.

Comment: The problem is i cant use any database due to certain restriction and available option will be text file. Excel file also not accepted since my program will run on red hat server

Comment: Then read the data into a hashmap as you suggested.

Comment: if i read the file and store into a string variable, what is the best method to store this string ? using 2d array ?hashmap or hashtable ?